# mysql if value = "0" then get other value

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have a table as follows:

```
+-----------+------+--------+
| stockcode | year | equity |
+-----------+------+--------+
| AALI      | 2016 |  17347 |
| AALI      | 2017 |  18236 |
| AALI      | 2018 |  18990 |
| AALI      | 2019 |  18521 |
| ABBA      | 2016 |    132 |
| ABBA      | 2017 |    104 |
| ABBA      | 2018 |    203 |
| ABBA      | 2019 |      0 |
| ABDA      | 2016 |   1232 |
| ABDA      | 2017 |   1375 |
| ABDA      | 2018 |   1334 |
| ABDA      | 2019 |   1254 |
+-----------+------+--------+
```

I need a query to get equity values based on the last year.
and if the value of the equity in 2019 = 0, get the value in 2018.

I tried to make it this way but it didn't work(blank page):

```
SELECT IF(equity <> '0', equity, SELECT equity FROM table_equity WHERE year='2018' AND stockcode='".$stockcode."') as equity FROM table_equity WHERE year='2019' AND stockcode='".$stockcode."'"
```

but when I try with code like this it's work:

```
SELECT IF(equity <> '0', "active", "nonactive") as equity FROM table_equity WHERE year='2019' AND stockcode='".$stockcode."'"
```

but of course the results were not what I wanted

So how to?

Comment: Maybe just pull where the `equity` is not `0` order by the `year` and select the most recent one?

Comment: What if a value is zero but previous year value is absent? What if a value for previous year is zero too?

Comment: @Akina 2018's value is never zero

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Show desired output for shown source data.

Comment: MySQL won't show any "blank page". Where does this happen instead?

Comment: @NicoHaase mysql in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are filtering by stockcode I would sort by year (desc) and then get the first row with non zero equity:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_equity 
WHERE stockcode='".$stockcode."' AND equity <> 0 AND year < YEAR(CURDATE())
ORDER BY year DESC
LIMIT 1"
```

And you should use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to prevent from sql injection attacks.

Comment: wonderful, it's work 100%, thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

I assume that both your year and equity columns are integers:

```
SELECT stockcode,year, equity FROM your_table 
WHERE year = 1919 and equity > 0 or year = 1918;
```

This should answer your question

Comment: sorry, it's not solve my problem, but thanks for your help

Comment: Why 1919/1918? Also consider `and` vs. `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 copies of a table - one will provide current year data and another for previous year. Use CASE operator and replace zero/null with the value for previous year (or zero if the data for previous year not exists in a table).

```
SELECT t1.stockcode,
       t1.year,
       CASE WHEN t1.equity > 0 
            -- get current value if it is positive
            THEN t1.equity
            -- get previous value if current is zero,
            -- and get zero if no data for previous year
            ELSE COALESCE(t2.equity, 0) END equity,
       -- show previous year value, or zero if it is not present
       COALESCE(t2.equity, 0) previous_year_equity
FROM source_table t1
LEFT JOIN source_table t2 ON t1.year = t2.year + 1
                         AND t1.stockcode = t2.stockcode
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afbed7d62f70a4e8693dc5c3cc376d63)

Comment: sorry, it's not solve my problem, but thanks for your help

Comment: @IbnulHusainan I add a fiddle - look at it, zero value is replaced with the value from the record for previous year. What's wrong?

Comment: I have a total of 134 data and the query above tells me the results of more than 500 data

Comment: @IbnulHusainan This means that your table contains duplicates by (stockcode, year).  You have not mentioned this, and you have not told what to do in this case (if one record contains zero and another not, if both are non-zero but not equal, and so on...). Your example data does not contain such duplicates too.